# getting use_zip64() not present error when trying to load heavy date frame to excel

Tags: pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I am trying to load the huge data frame to excel but getting error. If we don't use zip then file size is becoming very big which should not be.
Requesting for your input.

```py
def updated_files_with_new_work_sheet(fine_name,sheetpxl_name,df,index_value=False):
    try:
        excel_book = pxl.load_workbook(fine_name)
        with pd.ExcelWriter(fine_name, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            writer.book = excel_book

            writer.sheets = {
                worksheet.title: worksheet
                for worksheet in excel_book.worksheets
            }

            # writer.book.use_zip64()
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetpxl_name,index=index_value,engine='xlsxwriter')
            writer.save()

        gc.collect()
        # return
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # print("888File not found error***")
        df.to_excel(fine_name, sheet_name=sheetpxl_name,index=index_value)
```

Comment: You'll only need zip64 if your file will exceed 4 gigabytes. I would recommend against attempting to work with a 4 gigabyte Excel file anyway...

Comment: i am creating utility which will create merged file based 2 input file each file contains more then 120+ sheets. some data sheet contains around 1200+ rows and 1200+ columns . because of these sheets i am facing 2 issues
1. sudden spike in memory usage 
2.upon saving to excel, excel file is getting big. want to reduce the file size which is getting stored.

Comment: But could you even open such a file in Excel?

Comment: Yes, we are able to open excel and even able to load in data frame

Comment: It looks like you are trying to call a xlsxwriter workbook method, `use_zip64()`, on a openpyxl workbook object. You should probably move that to after the `to_excel()` when you set xlsxwriter as the engine.

Comment: requesting for addition details. am already using df.to_excel(fine_name, sheet_name=sheetpxl_name, index=index_value). also  am using engine="xlsxwriter". should i put writer.book.use_zip64() after  df.to_excel?

Comment: You can try that but I think you may have other problems with the way you are mixing the openpyxl and xlsxwriter engines.

Comment: yes.. tried and it didnt work . is there any way to compress the data frame before the copying to excel

Answer (score 1):

use_zip64() will be present when you select **engine='xlsxwriter'** in pd.ExcelWriter(fine_name, engine='xlsxwriter').

But this file compression won't work correctly. Excel file which was generated after "**df.to_excel()**" will be corrupted or won't open if you try to open it.

**Looking for the resolution for the below query-**
if we use 'openpyxl' as a engine in pd.ExcelWriter(fine_name, engine='openpyxl') then the object 'writer' does not have scope to use 'use_zip64()'.
Also when using 'xlsxwriter' as a engine in pd.ExcelWriter(fine_name, engine='xlsxwriter') with use_zip64() then generated .xlsx file is not opening.